# Can I get this in VSCode (for Angular, RxJS)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm

I've stumbled upon these snippets (?) in some tutorial for RxJS code in WebStorm. What is it called, and can I get the same for for VSCode, and for Angular maybe?

I know there is a "hover" function in VSCode, but I was thinking about the same?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's called **Parameter name inlay hints**. You can get them by:

1. going into VSCode Settings (**Ctrl + ,**)
2. search **parameter name**
3. On the left select **TypeScript**
4. On the right in drop down options you can select **none**, **all** or **literals**
5. You can do this for **JavaScript** or **Typescript**, or both

:-)